# Configuring SeriLog using ReadFrom.KeyValuePairs fails

Tags: c#, serilog

I'm trying to configure SeriLog using KeyValuePairs like this:
    `var config = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.KeyValuePairs(cfg.SeriLogSettings);`
where  SeriLogSettings is of type `Dictionary<string, string>`

the key value pairs are read from this yaml
`minimum-level: 'Verbose'`
`using:_CommandLineSettingsSerilogFullNetFx: 'Serilog.FullNetFx'`
`write-to:ColoredConsole.outputTemplate: '{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {CorrelationId}: {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}'`
`write-to:RollingFile.pathFormat: '..\..\LogsTests-{Date}.log'`
`write-to:RollingFile.outputTemplate: '{Timestamp:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff zzz} [{Level}] {CorrelationId}: {Message}{NewLine}{Exception}'`
`enrich:FromLogContext: ''`

However in the ColoredConsole the CorrelationId is not filled out (but the placeholder appears) when logging like this
`using (LogContext.PushProperty("CorrelationId", "YamlTest"))`
`{ logger.Information("Yaml config test"); }`

which works fine when configuring in code.
And also for RollingFile the outputTemplate is not picked up and the {CorrelationId} does not appear in the log file (not even the placeholder)

Anyone have experience using KeyValuePairs that might have advice

Comment: Any suggestions on this? @Nicholas-Blumhardt